# Drupal views: List of authors of nodes where node.type=abc and node.vocabulary_id=123

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

In drupal6 using views I want a (block) list of authors (with complete profile fields) of some specific node type AND taxonomy term.id OR vocabulary.id

Summarized query:
Views: type user
Argument: Term ID/Vocabulary ID
Filters: Author of Node type abc
Fields: All Profile/Content Profile Fields

How can I achieve such solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.  I found that if I filtered by node.type = 'blog' and set fields for the profile fields I was interested in, I could get a list or authors, but there would be duplicates.  Setting 'Distinct' to Yes didn't help because it was selecting out distinct nodes, not distinct users.

So I ended up creating a custom block to show this information with some code like this:

```
<?php
$block['subject'] = t('Bloggers');
    // Get a list of blog authors
    $result = db_query('SELECT DISTINCT u.uid, u.name FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {users} u ON n.uid = u.uid WHERE n.type = \'blog\'');
    $links = array();
    while ($blogger = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      $link = array();
      if (module_exists('profile')) {
        profile_load_profile($blogger);
      }
      if (!empty($blogger->profile_first_name) || !empty($blogger->profile_last_name)) {
        $link['title'] = $blogger->profile_first_name . (empty($blogger->profile_first_name) ? '' : ' ') . $blogger->profile_last_name;
      }
      else {
        $link['title'] = $blogger->name;
      }
      $link['href'] = 'blog/' . $blogger->uid;
      $links[] = $link;
    }
    $block['content'] = theme('links', $links, array('class' => 'flat-links'));
?>
```

Hope that helps.